# How to add a bottom border along row that has merged cells with VBA formatConditons

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where in column B the cells are merged with the row below. In the rest of the columns the rows are not merged.

I want to add a VBA code that draws a line across the bottom of the entire row along the bottom of the merged cells. It's as if I wanted to draw a bottom border every other row for all columns (except B where each merged cell would have the bottom border). I have tried using the following code but the border is not drawn under the merged cells

```
Sub FormatTest()

With Sheets("Test")

    With .Range("$B:$Z")
        .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=mod(row(),2)=0"
        With .FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlBottom)
          .LineStyle = xlContinuous
          .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          .TintAndShade = 0
          .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

Here is an example of what i want to achieve

[image: Example]

I want to achieve this with conditional formatting because the number of rows will change from time to time and i don't want to have borders on empty cells.

The photo is just an example because there are many rows and on different sheets I will have a different number of columns so I just want to apply it to the whole row... Can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest you add a screenshot of the expected result.

Comment: I have attached a photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using something along these lines:

(Just might need to tinker with the `row = 1` to get the correct starting position)

```
Dim row As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim letter As String

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your sheet name")
    ' clear previous borders
    .Range("A5:ZZ30000").Borders.Linestyle = xlNone
    ' add new borders
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' checks row 1 for last col
    letter = Split(.Cells(1, lCol).Address, "$")(1)
    For row = 1 To lastRow+1 Step 2
        With .Range("B" & row & letter & row).Borders(xlBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With  
    Next
End With
```

Comment: I would like to do this with conditional formatting because the number of rows may change.

Comment: Although this works v well. Is it possible to change the code so that it finds the last column, so that as i add or delete columns it will update automatically?

Comment: The only other problem i have with this is that if i run the code and lets say there are 200 rows, it will give me 200 borders. This is fine. If i then delete 100 rows and rerun the code, i still have the 200 borders on the page

Comment: @user3672422 added some code to find the last column per your 2nd comment...it searches row 1 for the last used column

Comment: @user3672422 Can you explain the leftover border problem some more? If you delete rows it still runs 200 columns? Maybe we should change with column `lastRow` checks to find the last used row (right now its col B)

Comment: I have managed to get around the borders being left over if the number of rows change by deleting all borders on the page before rerunning the code. Problem is i only want it to remove borders from row 5 down...

Comment: You can also use [Range.MergeArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) to get the Merged Cell that a Range is in, as part of a way to handle merged cells of any height

Comment: @Chronocidal thought about that but it appeared like the OP's sheet was pretty consistent with 2 merged cells every other cell